# Rotate Image without losing resolution

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation

I am having problem while rotating an Image Bitmap.When I rotate Image it lose its resolution.I want to rotate image everytime when user click on Button.Code on button's click is here:

```
matrix.postRotate(90);

bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap_rotate, 0, 0, bitmap_rotate.getwidth(),bitmap_rotate.getHeight(),matrix, true);
d_reflect = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);

image_view.removeAllViews();
image_view.setBackgroundDrawable(d_reflect);
```

Where image_view is LinearLayout and I want to set rotate LinearLayout.It lose its resolution everytime I rotate image.My original bitmap size is 300x300.I have googled a lot to find solution but none of them worked for me.
Any solution will be appreciated.Thanks in advance..

Comment: post your linearlayout code

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for rotating an image smoothly inside an imageview without creating an extra Bitmap.

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.setRotate(degrees);
image_view.setImageMatrix(m);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply..But image_view is my LinearLayout.And Bitmap is the screen shot of the Linear Layout.@Pratik

Comment: then you have to mention in your question, please edit your question with full detail

Answer (score 0):

Create a scaled bitmap with the desired width and height:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap_rotate, 300, 300, false);
```